# Database of English words with Russian translation

Tags: discussion

I have been building some web-based tools for learning using a [database of words](https://github.com/Badestrand/russian-dictionary) that comes from [OpenRussian](https://en.openrussian.org/dictionary).

For example the entry for the noun `машина` has the English translations:

```
car; machine, machinery, engine, mechanism
```

I am going to use this to make a facility to learn words that have the same root in bulk, e.g.

`свет` (light), `светать` (to grow light), `светлый` (bright), `светский` (wordly, secular), `свеча` (candle), `просвечивать` (to shine through), `просвещение` (enlightenment)...

Does anyone know either:

a) a database of English words with Russian translations
b) a book that lists English words with a similar etymology (for Russian speaking learners)

?

As an example of the latter, there is [this book](https://archive.org/details/georgez.patrickrootsoftherussianlanguagepassportbooks1981).